# Why are there two ways to comment code in HTML and which way to use?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, comments

I am new to HTML. I'm learning HTML from [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/pQN-pnXPaVg?t=2207). When I'm going to comment code in VS Code (using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>), this is by no means the way to show comments taught in [the YouTube video](https://youtu.be/pQN-pnXPaVg?t=2207), but a different way Ways to annotate code.

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>

    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> in VS Code, the result is as follows:

```
{% comment %} <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>

    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html> {% endcomment %}
```

When using the way taught in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/pQN-pnXPaVg?t=2207), the results are as follows:

```
<!--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>

    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
-->
```

Why are there two ways to comment code in HTML and which way to use? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which version of VScode are you using? this could be related to, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61348

HTML comments are correctly as per the video <!-- -->

Comment: Hi @Harshal, my VS Code version is version 1.72.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML comment is `<!-- your comment -->`. You should use this one.

`{% comment %}` seems like a framework template. If you save your file to HTML, this syntax appears in your documents.